# Share screen but use local keyboard

Tags: windows, macos, vnc

I have a PC (Windows 7) and a Mac (OS X Lion). Keyboard and mouse to each of them but only one screen. I know I could buy a DVI switch but it would be nice with a solution in software.

Is it possible to share the desktop of a Mac to a PC while still being able to use the keyboard connected to the Mac? I tried the built-in VNC screen sharing but it seems to overtake the local Mac keyboard and mouse (it's also quite slow). I would also prefer if it's the current Mac desktop that's shared and not a new session. A shared clipboard would also be nice.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 4):

Would [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) solve your problem?

[image]

Comment: That does not seem to be it because I have one screen, two keyboards, and two computers.

Comment: @JonasElfström maybe you should make your question more clear.

Comment: Is it more clear now?